# Getting Mouse Coordinates in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

Swift newbie here.

I've been having trouble with a task that should be trivial. All I want to do is get the x,y coordinates of the mouse cursor **on-demand**.  I would prefer *not* to wait for a mouse movement event to fire before I can grab the pointer's coords.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should take a look at NSEvent method [mouseLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/mouseLocation)

edit/update: **Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

If you would like to monitor events on any window when your app is active, you can add a LocalMonitorForEvents matching mouseMoved mask and if it is not active a GlobalMonitorForEvents. Note that you need set to your window property `acceptsMouseMovedEvents` to `true`

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    lazy var window: NSWindow = self.view.window!
    var mouseLocation: NSPoint { NSEvent.mouseLocation }
    var location: NSPoint { window.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) {
            print("mouseLocation:", String(format: "%.1f, %.1f", self.mouseLocation.x, self.mouseLocation.y))
            print("windowLocation:", String(format: "%.1f, %.1f", self.location.x, self.location.y))
            return $0
        }
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) { _ in
            print(String(format: "%.0f, %.0f", self.mouseLocation.x, self.mouseLocation.y))
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
    }
}
```

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/soi6hkgdeodbpg2/Mouse%20Location.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. Works perfectly. NSEvent is a goldmine. :)

Comment: Great solution @Leo! However, I couldn’t find out how to receive the `mouseLocation` if its position is outside of my custom window. I want to achieve some kind of color picker and want to draw a custom view besides the cursor. Would be great if you could lead me into the right direction!

Comment: @ixany sorry for the delay I just saw your question. You can use  `NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved) {  print(NSEvent.mouseLocation()) return $0 }` If you would like to monitor it when your app is not active just use global instead of local

Comment: Great answer, what would be the way to do it if I just want to track the mouse inside an NSView? (I'm new to Mac development as well..)

Comment: @Nils You can add a window property to your view controller using the lazy keyword as follow `lazy var window: NSWindow = self.view.window!` and then access the NSWindow property mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream `window.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream`. Check the last edit how you can monitor the mouse location and its position in the window.

Comment: Use **_self.view.window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true_**
Otherwise, declaring global **_window_ forced variable** cause retain cycle.

Comment: @MAfham I have not declared window as a global var. It is declared as a property of the view controller. It will live as long as the view controller does. Anyway `self.view.window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true` is ok as long as it is not used inside viewDidLoad where the window property is nil

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current mouse location in this way:

- Declare this in your view controller class:

  ```
  var mouseLocation: NSPoint? { self.view.window?.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream }
  ```
- Then, you can get the current mouse location and convert in your desired view coordinates:

  ```
  if let currentMouseLocation = self.mouseLocation{

       let pointInTargetView = self.**targetView**.convert(currentMouseLocation, from: self.view)

  }
  ```

Comment: this is the useful answer — thxu

Answer (score 0):

`NSEvent.mouseLocation` returns an `NSPoint` which is the position of the cursor in the screen.

It is mentioned in the accepted answer but not explicit.