# How to get mouse location when view is on hover in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI has [`onHover`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276934-onhover) for `View` to hook hover events, but it only gives feedback of hovered or not, which is a `Bool`.

How can I get the mouse location when `View` is on hover ?

Comment: Have you tried `NSEvent.mouseLocation` ? [This answer could also help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931403/getting-mouse-coordinates-in-swift)

Comment: @Alladinian thanks for responding. I will try use `NSView` in SwiftUI later