# How to detect mouse event outside current NSView in MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, appkit

Dues to I am using `CALayer's` mask attribute to draw and clip the content, the mask's size is like a `NSView` with a 10 pixel border, some of my content is larger than the current `NSView's` size with 10 pixel. But currently the mouse move event seems only detected when mouse move into the `NSView` area, I am trying to use `NSTrackingArea` the negative origin but seems not work?

Does anybody know how to detect the mouse move event outside current view?

Thanks,

Eric

More detail of my question:

I need to draw some content outside my view (which is inside a bigger view) and detect the mouse
event on my content and this is my current limitation that I can't use a larger view to draw my whole content, just consider it a special type of shadow and I need to detect mouse event on the shadow, so I use a mask to clip the whole content. Here is my code used to apple the mask. The margin is how much pixel I want to extend from my view. (apply this function to a NSView directly)

```
    func applyMaskToView(src: NSView, margin: CGFloat) {
    src.wantsLayer = true
    
    let mask = CALayer()
    mask.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
    let maskFrame = CGRect(x: -margin,
                           y: -margin,
                           width: src.frame.size.width + 2*margin,
                           height: src.frame.size.height + 2*margin )
    mask.frame = maskFrame
    src.layer?.masksToBounds = false
    src.layer?.mask = mask
    return
}
```

The code I used to apply tracking area is here (inside the NSView subclass):

```
    override func updateTrackingAreas() {

    var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?

    let options1: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.mouseEnteredAndExited,
                                            .activeAlways, 
                                            .mouseMoved,
                                            .enabledDuringMouseDrag]

    let options2: NSTrackingArea.Options = [options1, .inVisibleRect]

    for area in self.trackingAreas {
        self.removeTrackingArea(area)
    }

    if let activeBound = self.layer?.mask?.frame {
         trackingArea = NSTrackingArea.init(rect: activeBound, options: options1, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    }
    else {
        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea.init(rect: self.bounds, options: options2, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    }
    
    self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
    super.updateTrackingAreas()
    
}
```

If I don't use tracking area, I can't receive the mouse event in the margin area mention in the above code. However I can receive "mouse move" only now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932049/2303865

Comment: Thanks, did you mean I need to monitor global event on whole application other than my view? This view is just a small part of my full application. I can get mouse move of the view already, I problem is I can't get mouse move event just a little outside my view. So I want to find is there a easy way to detect the mouse move event base on my view's coordinate?

Comment: I found that my problem may caused by the option value "inVisibleRect" when I initial NSTrackingArea. Seems no meter what rectangle I set to initialize NSTrackingArea, once this option exist, all my rectangle became invalid? I am not sure is this the root cause of my problem?

Comment: After I remove the "inVisibleRect" option, the detection of "mouse move" correctly, but I still can't get "mouse drag", "mouse down", "mouse up" , ... mouse status related event after I set the Tracking area.

Comment: Why do you need to set a tracking area? Edit your question and post your code. Make sure to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have append more information to my question. I have a request that is a little like you need to have drag capability of  view's shadow.