# Converting NSPoint to CGPoint using NSPointToCGPoint

Tags: swift, macos, cgpoint, nspoint

How difficult can it be to access x and y coordinates from NSPoint...Can't believe it.

I get an NSPoint from following call:

`var mouseLoc = [NSEvent .mouseLocation]`

I need to access x and y coordinates. NSPoint does not offer a getter like CGPoint. I learned: I  have to cast into CGPoint but nothing that I found seems to work in latest Swift anymore:

`var p = (CGPoint)mouseLoc // error: Cannot convert value of type '[NSPoint]' (aka 'Array<CGPoint>') to expected argument type 'NSPoint' (aka 'CGPoint')`

`var p = NSPointToCGPoint(mouseLoc) // error: Cannot convert value of type '[NSPoint]' (aka 'Array<CGPoint>') to expected argument type 'NSPoint' (aka 'CGPoint')`

I am sure it's a complete beginner thing but I just don't get it.

Comment: `mouseLoc` is an array (multiple items) even if it contains only one.

Comment: You are creating an *array* of NSPoints. What you want is `let mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation`

Comment: `[ ... ]` is the syntax for an array literal in Swift, perhaps you are mixing that up with the syntax for Objective-C messages?

Comment: … and you never get the first error because this ObjC syntax to cast types  (`(CGPoint)mouseLoc`) is invalid in Swift.

Comment: @RobNapier: Actually `[NSEvent .mouseLocation]` *is* valid Swift :)

Comment: Thanks everyone.
As you expected I have messed up Obj-C with Swift.
I've changed [NSEvent .mouseLocation] to NSEvent.mouseLocation. Now it works.

Comment: @MartinR I always forget that spaces don't matter there… thank you

Comment: @user688262 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932049/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift uses a different syntax for calling instance or class methods than Objective-C.

```
// Objective-C
NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation]
```

translates to

```
// Swift
let mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation
```

whereas your Swift code creates an *array* containing a single `NSPoint`.

Also [`NSPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspoint) is a type alias for `CGPoint`:

```
typealias NSPoint = CGPoint
```

so you can simply use the same accessors:

```
// Swift
let mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation
let xCoord = mouseLoc.x
let yCoord = mouseLoc.y
```

Answer (score 1):

Here seems what *mouseLoc* is an array of *NSEvent*. Iterate through it and convert each point individually or use only one (first or last element).

Iterate like this:

```
let allPoints = mouseLoc.forEach { NSPointToCGPoint($0) }
```

But in this case you also will get an array, but now of *CGPoint*. You probably want to use only one of it, first or last.

But also maybe you have an array with only one element - use **.first**.