# Get mouse coordinates in Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I saw a similar question for AppKit ([Getting Mouse Coordinates in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931403/getting-mouse-coordinates-in-swift)), but it doesn't work in Catalyst because `NSViewController` is not available.

How do I get the coordinates of the mouse in **Mac Catalyst**?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [UIHoverGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uihovergesturerecognizer) to your UIView:

```
let hoverGestureRecognizer = UIHoverGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil)
addGestureRecognizer(hoverGestureRecognizer)
```

Then you can retrieve the coordinates of the mouse pointer from this gesturerecognizer in the following way:

```
public var pointerPosition: CGPoint? {
    guard (hoverGestureRecognizer.state == .began) || (hoverGestureRecognizer.state == .changed) else { return nil }
    return hoverGestureRecognizer.location(in: self)          
}
```